# TrackPopupMenu : Window disabled after menu dissapears

Tags: c++, windows, menu

I have added a popup menu to my app, and it is activated with this code:

```
HMENU contextMenu;
int CALLBACK WinMain(...)
{
    HMENU hContext = LoadMenu(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_CONTEXT_MENU));
    contextMenu = GetSubMenu(hContext, 0);
}

case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
{
    POINT pt;
    pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    ClientToScreen(hWndSDL, &pt);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWndSDL);
    TrackPopupMenu(contextMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON, pt.x, pt.y, 0, hWndSDL, NULL);
    break;
}
```

If I have the menu popped up, and then click the window's title bar, the menu dissappears, but the window still wont respond to any clicks outside the client area of the window.

I set a the KEYUP even for a letter on the keyboard to call ReleaseCapture(), and allows the non-client area of the window to start responding again. But this behavior should be automatic when the menu is dismissed shouldn't it?

anyone have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: sounds like wrong or no parent window for the menu

Comment: couldn't be, because the window that should be the parent stops responding outside the client area once the menu has popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you showing your menu in WM_RBUTTONDOWN handler?

It should be WM_CONTEXTMENU instead, and you must keep in mind it may be generated by the keyboard, and contain no coordinates.

Or at least use WM_RBUTTONUP inetead.

Comment: awesome! not quite sure why, but handling it in the RBUTTONUP event instead fixed it. Thanks =D

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the WM_RBUTTONDOWN message, use the WM_CONTEXTMENU message instead.  It is automatically generated when the default window procedure sees the WM_RBUTTONUP message.  Note UP, not DOWN.

Comment: for some reason, using this instead actually caused the popup menu to only show up when I click the titlebar =/ right clicking the client area does not make a popup

Comment: Nick, are you calling DefWindowProc where you should?

Comment: at the end of the window proc, I call this:

return CallWindowProc(sdlWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);

I wanted to add menus to an SDL(external graphics lib) window, so I had to hook it to get WM_COMMAND and such..I was hoping that wasn't the problem =-/

Comment: You should also use TPM_RIGHTBUTTON.